# Spring Retry and Recovery

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

is it possible to recover from an exception, and then retry again with Spring Retry?

In Java, would be something like

```
try{
    doSomething(); // throws Exception
}catch(Exception e){
    recoverException();
    doSomething(); // OK
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: yes of course. That is exactly what retry does. Go through this tutorial.  http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

Comment: @pvpkiran Is the RetryTemplate what am I looking for? :)

Comment: I used a 'listener' with a RetryTemplate in this case. The listener is calling the 'recoverException' above, and then calling callback.doWithRetry. Is the correct approach with RetryTemplate?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. Using '@Retryable' and '@Recover' should be good enuf in your case(from what ever little i understood)

Comment: @pvpkiran As far as I know, Recover only is called when Retryable has finished all the retries. I want to 'fix' the exception thrown by my method and then call again this method. This is, I want to be in the middle of the retries. i will update this question with my code when is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally,

I created a RetryListener and added it to my RetryTemplate. When some exception is thrown, I recover in the onError method from my RetryListener and then the RetryTemplate will retry automatically.

Something like

```
@Component
public class CustomRetryListener  extends RetryListenerSupport {

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, 
    RetryCallback<T, E> callback,
        Throwable throwable) {
        //recover from throwable
    }

}
```

And the retry template bean

```
@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate(CustomRetryListener listener) {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(2);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    retryTemplate.registerListener(listener);
    return retryTemplate;
}
```

Now you can inject the retryTemplate bean wherever you want and use the execute() method to recover from errors.